# Sliding the selector when move between two items of listview android

Tags: android, android-listview

I create a listview which has some buttons and a selector for user choose one of them.
I want to have a sliding when user move between two items. 
Like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyIQ2kH4h2w&index=12&list=PL46324CD70CD36B27 (03:12).
Any example or tutorial for me to do that?
Thanks a lot![image: See here]